# get 2nd highest sum in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table emp :

```
emp_id quantity 
1001   21
1001   10
1002   3
1002   5
1004   4
1004   5 
1004   8
```

i want to get the id having 2nd highest sum

```
so expected output is
1004 17
```

let me know how can this be done?

```
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sum_col DESC) as rownum
FROM(
    select order_id,
           sum(quantity) as sum_col
    from order1 
    group by order_id) t
    WHERE t.rownum=2
```

my query is giving error at line: WHERE t.rownum=2
However if i remove this line it works fine.
Let me know how can i put this condition

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: and what if two sums are tied for first place?

Comment: Use RANK() in CTE.

Comment: i wan to do first sum and then rank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT emp_id, 
                     SUM(quantity) `sum`, 
                     DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC) `rank`
              FROM test
              GROUP BY 1 )
SELECT emp_id, `sum`
FROM cte
WHERE `rank` = 2;
```

`DENSE_RANK()` needed (not `RANK()`) because if, for example, there is 2 rows with highest sum then they'll have RANK and DENSE_RANK equal to 1, but for the next sum value DENSE_RANK will be 2 whereas single RANK will be 3.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ffa93a72c72cf40d1bde7c8008c7adb2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT emp_id, SUM(quantity) as total_sum FROM emp
GROUP BY emp_id
ORDER BY total_sum DESC
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one:

SELECT emp_id, SUM(quantity) as total_sum FROM emp
GROUP BY emp_id
ORDER BY total_sum DESC
LIMIT 1,1;

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it